# RavenDB: Convert a document property to another type

Tags: c#, ravendb

I'm currently developing an application where I change the document a lot as I go forward (a small project to learn stuff like RavenDB). Some changes are not backwards compatible, which leads to JSON deserialization failures when I try to fetch documents.

Are there some way that I convert a property from the old type to a new one during deserialization? I'm using `Raven.Client.Lightweight` as client library.

Example:

I had a property named `AllProperties` in a class which was a `Dictionary<string,string>`. I changed the type from dictionary to a class called `MetadataItemCollection`.

Comment: Would this be the right way to actually do what you are trying? In other words shouldn't you be following second rule of SOLID, "Open Close Principle" where modules are open for extension but closed for modification? If you are changing property names then maybe you should be dropping the document and re-creating from scratch, then once you core structure is stable implement interfaces to allow extension?? Thoughts?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As in any other database-solution I suggest you roll your favourite migrations-framework for such kind of things. You will probably want to do [set-based operations](http://ravendb.net/documentation/set-based) on documents.

Interesting is, Ayende is going to publish two articles about ravendb migrations in the next few days, however, google has already indexed them and you can access these articles here:

[RavenDB Migrations: When to execute?](http://ayende.com/blog/66562/ravendb-migrations-when-to-execute?key=ce49237014234c44be9771c5064f0d01)

[RavenDB Migrations: Rolling Updates](http://ayende.com/blog/66563/ravendb-migrations-rolling-updates?key=4e0308d753ea4144ae9be7a3145ccb84)

Ayende, please forgive me... ;)

Answer (score 3):

If you are doing this during development, you are probably better off just deleting old docs and recreating them
If you are doing this in production, take a look at the posts that dlang has posted, they discuss those specific issues.